# Execute multiple statemens in a single STAssert… macro?

Tags: objective-c, testing, c-preprocessor

I’d like to execute more than one statement in the `STAssertXX` family of macros, is that possible? Something like:

```
STAssertTrue([foo doSomething] && [barDoSomethingElse], @"Should…");
```

The code above works for methods that return booleans, I’d like something similar for `void` return types:

```
STAssertNoThrow({
    [foo doSomething];
    [bar doSomethingElse];
}, @"Should…");
```

Of course, here the preprocessor complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since any valid C code is also valid Objective-C; you can use the `,` operator from C for a single argument, as long as you use it in parenthesis.

Like this:

```
NSAssertNoThrow(([foo doSomething], [bar doSomethingElse]), @"Whatever");
```

The `,` operator lets you composite several expressions as a single statement returning the value of the last expression.

I would advise **strongly against** using this in `STAssert…` statements since you will loose important information about which tests that failed.

Comment: That’s it! I thought of the comma operator, but it did not occure to me that I can use the extra pair of parens to make a difference from the argument-list comma. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is what I’ve got so far:

```
STAssertNoThrow(^{
    [foo doSomething];
    [bar doSomethingElse];
}(), @"Whatever");
```

But maybe there’s an easier solution?